# ¿Tengo un problema con mis crosstab datawindow Powerbuilder?

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, pivot, powerbuilder

Todo este problema viene porque desde Powerbuilder tanto el IDE como .EXE, cuando realizo el retrieve de mis crosstab Datawindow. Estos devuelven los datos, pero a la hora de mostrarlos, el Datawindow empieza a parpadear y luego el aplicativo peta y se cierra.

Por esa razón estoy intentando crear una query que haga lo que hacía el datawindow y si me sale, empezar a transformar todos los crosstab DW por Tabular DW y asignarle esta nueva query.

Pero estoy viendo que hacerlo dinámico como quiero es difícil.
Alguien se encontró un problema similar, con sus Crosstab Datawindow, todo esto en PowerBuilder 2019 R3.

deseo saber si puedo reducir esta consulta dinámica con variables a una sola select más compleja sin la necesidad de utilizar variables. (La query de bajo es un ejemplo realizado con la BDDemo)

Lo necesito porque la tecnología que utilizo trata de mucho mejor manera las selects.

```
DECLARE @dml AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
 
SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
       + QUOTENAME(Months)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT  DATEPART(MONTH, SOH.OrderDate) Months
         FROM sales.SalesOrderHeader SOH
         JOIN sales.SalesOrderDetail SOD ON SOH.SalesOrderId = SOD.SalesOrderId
    GROUP BY YEAR(SOH.OrderDate),
DATEPART(MONTH, SOH.OrderDate)) AS Months
 
 --Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
SET @dml = 
  N'SELECT SalesYear, ' +@ColumnName + ' FROM
  (
  SELECT YEAR(SOH.OrderDate) AS SalesYear, 
           DATEPART(MONTH, SOH.OrderDate) Months,
           SUM(SOH.SubTotal) AS TotalSales
   FROM sales.SalesOrderHeader SOH
         JOIN sales.SalesOrderDetail SOD ON SOH.SalesOrderId = SOD.SalesOrderId
    GROUP BY YEAR(SOH.OrderDate),
    DATEPART(MONTH, SOH.OrderDate)) AS T
    PIVOT(SUM(TotalSales) 
           FOR Months IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'
--Print @DynamicPivotQuery
--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @dml
```